# Но(,) когда(,)... — нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

> а) От первого моего удара он легко увернулся, будто не был ранен; но(,) когда(,) вместо того, чтобы контратаковать, он остановил мой меч голой ладонью, я понял, что шансов у меня нет совсем.
>
> б) От первого моего удара он легко увернулся, будто не был ранен; но(,) когда он остановил мой меч голой ладонью, вместо того, чтобы контратаковать, я понял, что шансов у меня нет совсем.

Интересует пунктуация в обоих случаях.

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаемый вариант:

От первого моего удара он легко увернулся, будто не был ранен; но когда, вместо того чтобы контратаковать, он остановил мой меч голой ладонью, я понял, что шансов у меня нет совсем.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Вместо того чтобы - не расчленяется в середине предложения.

2) Союз НО относится ко всей структуре, а не к главной части "я понял", поэтому запятая после союза не ставится.

Comment: А как проверить, относится какой-либо союз ко всей структуре или нет?

Comment: @Анака, надо просто попытаться убрать вложенную часть без союза, если фраза останется грамматически правильной, значит союз относится ко всей части.

Answer (score 0):

На стыке союзов или союзов и союзных слов ***(и хотя, но когда, и если; что когда, что куда, который если и др.)*** запятая ставится тогда, когда после придаточной части нет союза **но** или второй части двойного союза — **то** или **так**.
Например:
***Ребёнок что-то лепетал, и, хотя мать слышала это не раз, сердце её переполнялось радостью.***
Но:
***Ребёнок что-то лепетал, и хотя мать слышала это не раз, но сердце её переполнялось радостью.***

Синтаксические конструкции, начинающиеся с союза **вместо того чтобы**, выделяются с двух сторон знаками препинания. При этом первый знак препинания может ставиться либо перед составным союзом, либо между его частями (перед словом **чтобы**).

***Сказавши это, он,*** вместо того чтобы идти домой, **пошёл совершенно в противную сторону, сам того не подозревая** (Н. Гоголь. Шинель).

Comment: Я знакома с этим правилом и не могу понять: в случае с "но(,) когда" "то" вообще может иметь место? 
От первого моего удара он легко увернулся, будто не был ранен; но когда он остановил мой меч голой ладонью, ТО вместо того, чтобы контратаковать, я понял, что шансов у меня нет совсем. 
Может, я чего-то не понимаю, но это "то" тут звучит ужасно.

Comment: Немного громоздкая конструкция, но ничего ужасного в ней нет

Answer (score 0):

Запятые необходимы. В сложноподчиненном предложении встречаются 2 простых (НО + КОГДА) и простой и составной союзы (КОГДА + ВМЕСТО ТОГО ЧТОБЫ).

И вариант с ТО:

*От первого моего удара он легко увернулся, будто не был ранен, **но когда** он остановил мой меч голой ладонью, вместо того чтобы контратаковать, **то** я понял, что шансов у меня нет совсем.* (Запятая не нужна, так как встречаются простой и двойной союз, НО + КОГДА... ТО).

"Вместо того чтобы" здесь лучше не разделять запятой, так как он интонационно целостный, интонация предложения и без того достаточно прерывистая.

Иногда правило о встрече союзов в сложноПОДЧИНЕННОМ предложении путают с правилом об общей части в сложноСОЧИНЕННОМ предложении.

В сложносочиненном общим может быть: второстепенный член, вводное слово, придаточное или поясняемое предложение. **Противительный союз не является объединяющим элементом** и не влияет на постановку запятой перед И:

*Он спрятался, но открылась дверь, и в комнату вошла старуха.*

Answer (score 0):

> а) От первого моего удара он легко увернулся, будто не был ранен;
>   но(,) когда(,) вместо того, чтобы контратаковать, он остановил мой меч
>   голой ладонью, я понял, что шансов у меня нет совсем.
>
> б) От первого моего удара он легко увернулся, будто не был ранен;
>   но(,) когда он остановил мой меч голой ладонью, вместо того, чтобы
>   контратаковать, я понял, что шансов у меня нет совсем.

Я бы в обоих случаях обошёлся **без запятых** на месте скобок.

Считаю части, находящиеся **после точки с запятой**, самостоятельными предложениями. А "[в начале предложения не разделяются запятой сочинительный и подчинительный союзы, а также подчинительный союз и союзное слово](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134)".

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен на 100%:

а) От первого моего удара он легко увернулся, будто не был ранен. Но когда, вместо того чтобы контратаковать, он остановил мой меч голой ладонью, я понял, что шансов у меня нет совсем.

б) От первого моего удара он легко увернулся, будто не был ранен. Но когда он остановил мой меч голой ладонью, вместо того чтобы контратаковать, я понял, что шансов у меня нет совсем.

Причём `ранен. Но когда` можно заменить на `ранен, но, когда`.

Post Scriptum: Зачем Вам «но», Вам нужно «и» — второе предложение не противопоставляется первому, а, наоборот, дополняет его. Или, на худой конец, «а».